# Finding the list of items for particular XSLT file in sitecore 6.2

Tags: sitecore

I want to generate a report of all the list of items where a particular xslt is been used in the presentation tab. Is there any way to generate the report using a query or programatically.

Comment: You have already asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118448/find-all-the-item-that-is-using-a-common-sublayout-in-sitecore-6-2-0 and it was answered.
Sublayout or rendering, is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things programatically you have to look at the LinkDatabase.

Depending on what version of Sitecore you could use the following to build on:

Sitecore 5:

```
var linkdatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetLinkDatabase();
linkdatabase.GetReferers(Sitecore.Context.Item); //use any item
```

Sitecore 6:

```
var linkdatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetLinkDatabase();
linkdatabase.GetReferrers(Sitecore.Context.Item); //use any item
```

That should be enough for you to do the rest.

- Christian